# IIS binding migration azure

Tags: azure, iis, migration

We are trying to migrate our ASP.NET web apps to an Azure VM.  We have about 5 apps under our website, but we need to do these one by one.  The problem is when we migrate one app to an Azure VM IIS, we need to maintain the URL and not disturb the 4 remaining web apps.  Below is an image better explaining what I need to do:

[See Image](https://ibb.co/nHThgU)

Notice I need to maintain the original URL (https://www.site1.com/App1-1) when moved to the Azure VM.  We had thought about doing a reverse proxy for that one app, but I think that would put too much extra traffic going back and forth.

I know this is probably not the best way of migrating things to Azure. Refactoring the app is slated for the future.  This is a "lift and shift" interim solution.  Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

1. Migrated the app to Azure VM and test it first to confirm it working
2. Configure the custom DNS entry to point to the app in Azure. You can read more here
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/dns/dns-domain-delegation
3. Switch off the app from the local server once DNS entry in Azure is active.
4. Migrate other apps

Comment: Not sure how does it helps when the app names are not part of the domain name.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you have a DNS server locally, you can map the VM address to the custom https://www.site1.com/App1-1  address.